# How to plot emission spectrum using gaussian?

Tags: gaussian, spectroscopy, excited-states

I'm trying to learn how to plot emission spectrum for my system, but, as an initial test case, I'm trying to do this for methane.

I calculated the optimized geometry of the ground state, then I launched a single point  `TD(nstates=5)` calculation, which is how we obtain the absorption spectra since absorption spectra is obtained from the optimized ground state geometry.

From this latter output file, I launched an `opt td(nstates=5,singlets,root=1)` in order to optimize the geometry of the first excited state. However, the Gaussian calculation crashed with the error link1e. How can I fix this issue and obtain the emission spectrum?

here are my steps
first step: optimization of GS

```
%chk=CH4.chk
# B3lyp/3-21g opt freq SCRF=(PCM,read,solvent=CH2Cl2)

opt first step  ground state optimization

0 1
 C                  0.62913910   -0.49668873    0.00000000
 H                  0.98579352   -1.50549874    0.00000000
 H                  0.98581194    0.00770946    0.87365150
 H                  0.98581194    0.00770946   -0.87365150
 H                 -0.44086090   -0.49667555    0.00000000


   radii=UAKS
```

second step: calculating excited states

```
%chk=CH4TD.chk
#  b3lyp/3-21g  TD(NStates=5) SCRF=(PCM,read,solvent=CH2Cl2)

second  step calculating excited states 

0 1
 C                  0.00000000    0.00000000    0.00000000
 H                  0.63143400    0.63143400    0.63143400
 H                 -0.63143400   -0.63143400    0.63143400
 H                 -0.63143400    0.63143400   -0.63143400
 H                  0.63143400   -0.63143400   -0.63143400

   radii=UAKS
```

third step: optimization of the first ES

```
%chk=CH4emission.chk
# opt td=(nstates=5,singlets,root=1) b3lyp/3-21g scrf=(solvent=ch2cl2,read,pcm) 


optimizing first excited state

0 1
 C                  0.00000000    0.00000000    0.00000000
 H                  0.63143400    0.63143400    0.63143400
 H                 -0.63143400   -0.63143400    0.63143400
 H                 -0.63143400    0.63143400   -0.63143400
 H                  0.63143400   -0.63143400   -0.63143400


 radii=UAKS
```

the optimization failled with this error

```
Error termination request processed by link 9999.
 Error termination via Lnk1e in C:\G09W\l9999.exe
```

Comment: Can you include your input/output? If the output is too long, you can just include the error message that is printed when the calculation fails (and ideally any earlier warnings)

Comment: I think we'll need more of the output file to understand the error. There can be a lot of reasons for that termination request. Is there any way you can put the output file up, e.g., pastebin.com or a similar site?

Comment: You can look for some similar question asked on a number of platforms. Here, I am attaching one [link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_know_about_the_Error_termination_via_Lnk1e_in_soft_g09_l1002exe_from_the_optimization_and_frequency_calculations). Hope this will help you.....

Comment: @anupama are you able to write an answer? Alme999 have you figured this out yet? Please update us!